# Can't change to other language anymore

Tags: keyboard

I sed to can change language into etc(BM, CHINESE, ENG )but now all I can use is ENG. Why ones that happen when is used to work perfectly?

Comment: We need more information in order to help you. As a workaround you can try using [SwiftKey](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.touchtype.swiftkey) as alternative keyboard. Switching languages there is easy.

Comment: Add a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Well, that issue have become common like Chinese as default or vice versa. But you can fix it by using [Android language changer apps](http://softstribe.com/lists/7-best-language-switching-android-apps-to-fix-language-issues/) or [Chinese to english](http://softstribe.com/android/quick-fix-how-to-change-the-chinese-language-in-android/).